# javascript to show/hide table

Tags: javascript

```
<tr>
        <td><form:checkbox path="ftpScanEvents" id="chk" onclick="showMe('div1',this);"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="_ftpScanEvents"/>
            FTP Scan Events</td>
    </tr>           
    <tr><td colspan="4">
        <table id="div1" style="display:none">
        <tr><td>Host Name</td><td>Directory</td><td>User Name</td><td>Password</td></tr>
        <tr><td><form:input path="hostName" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="directory" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="password" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td></tr>
```

javascript:

```
function showMe (it, chkbox) {
          var rr = (chkbox.checked) ? "block" : "none";
          document.getElementById(it).style.display = rr;
        }
```

I can hide/show it on checkbox selection. But, what I need is on page load, if checkbox is checked show it else hide...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an onload event. Add this to the bottom part of your HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        showMe('div1',document.getElementById('chk'));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: just now, i realized that your code is using an invalid HTML for checkbox. are you getting a checkbox there? the code should be: `<form> ... <input type="checkbox" id="chk" /> .... </form>`